# Show equality of two krylov spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

A bijective funktion f:V->V and a m-krylov-space K_m(f,v)=spann{v,f(v),..,f^(m-1)(v)} are given.

We have to show f(K_m(f,v))=K_m(f,v), so practically spann{v,f(v),..,f^(m-1)(v)}=spann{f(v),f^2(v),..,f^m(v)} if i understand it correctly.
I don't quite see how i can use the bijectivity of f here

Comment: Please use latex properly. How is someone supposed to read this? It looks like a copy paste from a pdf to be honest

Comment: Sry bro. Don't know how to use it

Comment: A willingness to learn never a bad thing. The reason this post isn't getting any responses is because it is unreadable.